# BitTorrent Sync on RPi with dynamic IP addresses, how to set it up?

Tags: backup

I've got a synology DS-212j with the **BTSync** client set up, and I've also set it up on a Raspberry Pi on the my LAN succesfully. The sync directories work perfect, and now that the test phase goes well, I'd like to **use the RPi on my parent's house** as a way to have a backup for some of my files here at home.

The only thing that I am not sure about is how to configure the BTSync client there, because **it's a remote location and the IP is dynamic**. I guess I must use DynDNS or some free alternative (I've seen [DNSexit](http://www.dnsexit.com/Direct.sv?cmd=dynDns)) and then configure somehow a fixed domain (I should then set up a lightweight webserver on the RPI as well?).

What would be the appropiate steps to be able to **sync files** from my house to my parent's RPi through BitTorrent Sync? I'd like to do this with this client, although I know using rsync for example could be an option too... But BTSync runs in the background and once you configure you can leave it running comfortably.

Comment: To make your question relevant, Add something about Raspberry Pi in it please.

Comment: The question is IMHO related to RPi. In the help center it says: "For the most part this includes: [...] Software that runs on the Raspberry Pi". And BitTorrent Sync (btsync) runs from the RPi as one of the nodes of my sync scenario. I consider this question and answer useful... can you explain why is it offtopic?

Comment: As you can see it was closed off by other ppl.. because i knew they would do that even though you are correct with the quote from the Help Centre... it was just predictable.. that is why i said put something about Pi in there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Bittorrent Sync uses Bittorrent technology that is inherently peer-to-peer and IP-independent.**

You do not need need a fixed Internet IP.

*This is my assumption as internal working is not revealed anywhere ...

*Each client makes a small amount of encrypted data (based on secret i presume) and stores it somewhere. Where I am not exactly sure- either on a bittorrent server or on other clients that share this data somehow (There are no details on the website how tracking is done)*

When you add a secret on a client it gets the tracking data and it knows what IP's are active, what ports to connect to it might even use this tracking system to get the remote client to initiate connection to overcome NAT and Firewall issues.

In conclusion, the system is designed to know where clients are and what folders are shared without any knowledge of networking, ports or schmorts.

It just works! It amazing and easy.

*My network has become so complex now, between work shared folders, home folders, server retentions and friends folders. I never needed to open any ports or configure any firewalls.*

**How to install Bittorrent synch from repository**

```
sudo gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 6BF18B15
sudo gpg --armor --export6BF18B15 | sudo apt-key add -
sudo echo deb http://debian.yeasoft.net/btsync wheezy main contrib non-free >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/btsync.list
sudo echo deb-src http://debian.yeasoft.net/btsync wheezy main contrib non-free >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/btsync.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install btsync
```

You can then add the secret from your computers client on the the remote computer client and it will start to synchronize. You can do this on as many Pi's as you like just make sure you have enough disk space :)

When you are installing it on a headless system the only port is the web interface port that you might need but you should not forward that to the internet. It would be better to SSH into the box via 22 port and tunnel into the torrent interface. If you really must forward the web gui port make sure to secure the web interface with a proper password.

You can install [Bittorrent sync application](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync/technology.html) that gives you a native GUI for your platform. It does not allow you to mange remote location though just folders synchronized with the current machine.

> For example: The Pi could be running headless connected to an external
>   1Terrabyte hard drive that stores all your files and your parents
>   files. Then on your computer at your remote location you install the
>   native client on Windows and you get the copy off all the data. You
>   then also install a client on your parents computer- This is nice
>   because BTSynch knows you are on LAN and synchronizing will very
>   fast. So the Pi is "like a dropbox server" and you and your parents
>   are the clients. You do not have to share the entire drive you can just select
>   specific folders like Photos shared amongst your self and parents but you might want
>   to backup your documents at home and your parents do not have to see that at all.
>   You can then share specific folders within Photos with a 1 time key or read only 
>   attributes for friends or other family.

**Security**

And if you are worried about all the NSA hacking Bittorrent apparently uses a proper open source, non backdoored implementation of AES-256 with proper cryptographic engines.

Comment: Promising!! If BTSync really takes care of all of this and IPs aren't needed, then the setup will be really easy :D I'll try this on the weekend and will let you know if it worked. If so, rest assured I'll upvote your answer. Thanks!